# Getting the last row with a certain column from each day in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called logs that consists of a few columns.

id | state | result | timestamp

I need to all the rows with the state 'success-changed', but they appear at random, some days they don't and some they do twice. So in cases there is more than one per day I need to get the last one.

Can someone show me how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select l.*
from logs l
where l.result = 'success-changed' and
      l.timestamp = (select max(l2.timestamp)
                     from logs l2
                     where l2.result = 'success-changed' and
                           date(l2.timestamp) = date(l.timestamp)
                    );
```

This assumes that `timestamp` is stored as a `datetime` value.

Comment: you don't need condition "and date(l2.timestamp) = date(l.timestamp)"

Comment: @AdamSilenko . . . The question is asking for the last such record per day.  This is one way to accomplish that.

Comment: you right. but only because you don't have group by, date is in timestamp, you don't need join by this because, if you have join by timestamp, and group by date(timestamp) in subquery you get one timestamp for day. there is few more method to do that :)

Comment: @AdamSilenko . . . If you used `group by`, you would have to change the `=` to `in`.  Both are reasonable solutions in this case.  In other cases, the correlated subquery might be faster with the right index.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need add order by and group by to select...

```
select id , state , max(timestamp)
from logs 
where result = 'success-changed'
group by id , state
order by 3 desc
```

if you need id, state for last timestamp and for every day where result = 'success-changed', maybe this will be faster:

```
select id, state, timestamp
from logs l 
where result = 'success-changed'
and exists(
  select date(timestamp) 
  from logs 
  where result = 'success-changed'
  group by date(timestamp)
  having max(timestamp) = l.timestamp) 
order by 3 desc
```

you should have index on timestamp field.

Comment: That still gives out multiple rows per day. https://gist.github.com/RonMelkhior/085ce6df379704844e25

Comment: @RonMelkhior I think it will work you group by `date(timestamp)` instead of `id,state`

Comment: if you need id and state for one day try add to group by DATE(timestamp)

Comment: Using this: 'select id, result, max(timestamp) from cronlogs where state= SUCCESS-CHANGE group by timestamp order by 3 desc' but it still produces the problem of having 2 rows from the same day, while i only need the later one.

Comment: what a result you need? last id for day ? now you get all id and state for day.

Comment: or maybe you need last state for id and day?

Comment: I need the last id, result, timestamp from every day where state is success-change